# Optimize a Solver function

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, solver

I'm trying to set up a "Solver" function to optimize the value of "gfc" to zero varying (and finding) the variable "fc" on equation below. The parameters are given.

```
f0 = 6
f1 = 1
k = 2
ft = 0.3

gfc = ft-((f0-fc)/k)+((f1/k)*ln((fc-f1)/(f0-f1)))
```

Solving this function on Excel, I found the value of fc=5.504.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `uniroot` to find where a function equals zero:

```r
f0 = 6
f1 = 1
k = 2
ft = 0.3

gfc = function(fc) {
    ft - ((f0 - fc) / k) + ((f1 / k) * log((fc - f1) / (f0 - f1)))
}

uniroot(gfc, interval = c(f0, f1))
#> $root
#> [1] 5.504386
#> 
#> $f.root
#> [1] 6.72753e-09
#> 
#> $iter
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $init.it
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $estim.prec
#> [1] 6.103516e-05
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that what you mean is that you want to solve for the value of `fc` for which `gfc` equals zero.  We assume `fc` lies between `f0` and `f1`.  In that case using the constants in the question we have the following base R solutions. (Additionally packages with such functionality include nleqslv and rootSolve.)

**1) optimize** we can minimize gfc^2:

```
gfc <- function(fc) ft-((f0-fc)/k)+((f1/k)*log((fc-f1)/(f0-f1)))
optimize(function(x) gfc(x)^2, c(f0, f1))
```

giving:

```
$minimum
[1] 5.504383

$objective
[1] 4.777981e-12
```

**2) uniroot** or we can do it directly using `uniroot`:

```
u <- uniroot(gfc, c(f0, f1))
```

giving:

```
> u
$root
[1] 5.504386

$f.root
[1] 6.72753e-09

$iter
[1] 5

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

**3)** We can also solve this directly without any function like `optimize` or `uniroot` by rewriting

```
gfc(fc) = 0
```

as this where we have moved the first term of gfc to the LHS and then isolated fc in that term putting everything else on the RHS.

```
 fc = f0 - k*(ft + ((f1/k)*log((fc-f1)/(f0-f1))))
```

Writing this as:

```
fc = f(fc)
```

we just iterate f.

```
f <- function(fc) f0 - k*(ft + ((f1/k)*log((fc-f1)/(f0-f1))))
fc <- (f0 + f1)/2  # starting value
for(i in 1:10) fc <- f(fc)

fc
## [1] 5.504386
```

**4) brute force** Another approach is to evaluate gfc at many points and just pick the one for which gfc^2 is least.  The finer you subdivide the interval the more accurate the answer.

```
s <- seq(f0, f1, length = 100000)
g <- gfc(s)
s[which.min(g^2)]
## [1] 5.504395
```

### Graphics

We can show the solution:

```
curve(gfc, f0, f1)
abline(h = 0, v = u$root, lty = 2)
axis(1, u$root, round(u$root, 3))
```

[image]